# Changing from an ESTA VWP to a E3-D

Tags: usa, visa, australian-citizens

My fiancee has secured a working visa in USA. We are both Australian citizens and I am planning on joining him. We are leaving Mid-October, and I will only be on an ESTA VWP 90 day visa, as I will be applying for a E3-D once we're married. We are planning on getting married in December in USA.

Question: Am I able to change from an ESTA to a E3-D if I go to a US Embassy in Canada or even London, or do I have to come back to Australia to do so?

If I do have to come back to Australia, does anyone know how long this will take to get if I book in my appointment prior to flying back.

Comment: It doesn't answer the question but I'd point out that if you obtained a B-2 visa before you left you could change status to E-3D without leaving the US (VWP entrants can't change status). Unmarried partners of non-immigrants are sometimes granted B-2 visas to accompany them, a stay of up to a year can be granted. You would still have to eventually get a visa for the new status for travel purposes, but you could interview in Canada and wouldn't have to leave the US until the interview date.

Comment: @Dennis and a visa would not be necessary if there was no plan to leave the US and return in E-3D status.